# FOOn(i, j, k) notation for nd numpy array in weave.inline()'s support_code argument? Are there any alternatives?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, inline

I want to use `support_code` to define functions that interact with nd numpy arrays. Inside the `code` argument, the `FOO3(i, j, k)` notation works, but only in it, not in `support_code`.Something like this:

```
import scipy
import scipy.weave
code = '''return_val = f(1);'''
support_code = '''int f(int i) {
    return FOO3(i, i, i);
}''''
foo = scipy.arange(3**3).reshape(3,3,3)
print(scipy.weave.inline(code, ['foo'], support_code=support_code))
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of support code is mainly to do some includes. In your case, I guess the function should look something like this:

```
import scipy
import scipy.weave

def foofunc(i):
    foo = scipy.arange(3**3).reshape(3,3,3)
    code = '''#do something lengthy with foo and maybe i'''
    scipy.weave.inline(code, ['foo', 'i']))
    return foo[i,i,i]
```

You don't need support code at all, for what you're trying to do. You also don't have any speed improvement, when you try to do a function return in C instead of doing that in python, also array access is neglectable compared to the cost of the function call. To get a better idea, when and how weave can help you, to speed up your code, have a look [here](http://www.scipy.org/PerformancePython).